# OPC UA connection between KEPServerEX (server) and WinCC explorer V7.3 (cliënt)

Tags: configuration, plc, opc, scada

I'm trying to connect a Simatic S7-1500 PLC to a WinCC SCADA system by OPC UA. The OPC UA server is KEPServerEX. I made a dummy program for the PLC with blinking light, and I want WinCC to read this data (by OPC UA). The connection between the PLC and KEPServerEX is fine (by ethernet), but I cannot get the OPC UA connection done between KEPServerEX (server) and WinCC explorer V7.3 (cliënt). Those software are both on the same PC. Even if I have not enabled encryption/signing security. I have configured the cliënt in WinCC like the picture below:

[image]

When I select OPC DA instead of OPC UA, and test the server, it works. OPC UA in KEPServerEX is enabled. Anyone who would like to help me out with the configuration? Sorry if my question is unclear.

Thanks in advance,

Roel

Comment: Please post an error message you are getting. I do not know how the WinCC OPC UA client should be configured, but it does not look right that for "OPC UA", you would enter "Kepware.KEPServerEX.V6". That is a ProgID for OPC-DA (COM-based). OPC UA connection requires an endpoint address (opc,tcp://..., http://..., or so).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did not get a error message, it just does not want to connect. With opc.tcp:// (the server endpoint of OPC UA Configuration Manager) it still does not connect.

Comment: and opc.tcp://localhost:4840 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to configure the ports in your firewall! Then you can browse the UA server in WinCC.